# Язык ошибок Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

в Yii2, шаблон basic при неправильности ввода логина или пароля выдает ошибку incorrect username or password, язык в web.php выставил ru-RU. Ошибки валидации отображаются корректно на русском, в чем дело?

Answer (score 2):

В basic шаблоне оно вписано харкодом в LoginForm.php:

```
$this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
```

Comment: действительно, спасибо!